# React Native async function returns promise even with "await"

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

My react-native component is supposed to return some svg that gets returned by an API call. I am using an async function with await but my function still returns a promise as if the promise has not resolved yet.
I know this question has been asked many times but I am still not sure why my return statement doesn't return the resolved promise as I am using 'await'.

Shouldn't the return statement be returning the resolved promise and not the promise itself? I should note I don't want to console log the value but return it directly.

```
const getQRCode = async () => {
  try {
       const response = await qrFetch;
       const responseText = await response.text();
      // console.log(responseText)
       return responseText;
   } catch(error){
        console.error(error);
      }
}

const xml = getQRCode()

console.log("--XML DATA HERE--")
console.log(xml)

export default function QRCodeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaContainer}>
      <SvgXml xml={xml} width="100%" height="100%" />;
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

### Update

My updated code is now contained within an async function but I have a new error as follows.

```
async function main(){
  const getQRCode = async () => {
    try {
         const response = await qrFetch;
         const responseText = await response.text();
         return responseText;
     } catch(error){
          console.error(error);
        }
  }
  const xml = await getQRCode()
  return xml
}

export default function QRCodeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaContainer}>
      <SvgXml xml={main()} width="100%" height="100%" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

### Error

```
TypeError: source.split is not a function. (In 'source.split('\n')', 'source.split' is undefined)
```

This is likely something to do with the react-native-svg package I am using. I checked the typeOf 'xml' variable and it is indeed a string. I will likely ask a separate question or report the issue on the packages github repo.

Comment: You're not calling the function via `await`; you're just directly calling it.

Comment: Also, while it's hard to say from what you posted, `await qrFetch` should *probably* be `await qrFetch()`

Comment: An `async` function always returns a `Promise`, so that kind of behavior is totally expected. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

Answer (score 3):

An `async function` will return a `promise`.

If you want to get the content of this promise, you must `await` the result:

```
const xml = await getQRCode()
```

### Error

```
  export default function QRCodeScreen({ navigation }) {
    const [xml, setXml] = useState(null)
    
    async function main() {
      ...your function
      // remove return
      // replace by:
      const tempXml = await getQRCode()

      setXml(tempXml)
    }
    
    useEffect(() => {
      main()
    }, [])

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaContainer}>
      <SvgXml xml={xml} width="100%" height="100%" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
```

}

Comment: Right I see that makes sense, but would I not need to have the above statement contained within another async function. When you specify await outside an async function in react-native it throws an error at you - thanks.

Comment: That's right, you can't use `await` without an `async` function. If that's not possible to do in your use case, you'd have to resort to an old-school `.then` callback to do something with the resolved data.

Comment: Check my updated code, also thank you for your answers :)

Comment: Edited my answer

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```js
const getQRCode = async () => {
  try {
       const response = await qrFetch;
       const responseText = await response.text();
      // console.log(responseText)
       return responseText;
   } catch(error){
        console.error(error);
      }
}

const xml = await getQRCode()

console.log("--XML DATA HERE--")
console.log(xml)

export default function QRCodeScreen({ navigation }) {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.safeAreaContainer}>
      <SvgXml xml={xml} width="100%" height="100%" />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

**BTW:**
You better set ; at the end of the line `everywhere`, or `nowhere` to be more consistent.
I've removed the `;` behind <SvgXML... ;)

Comment: Thanks for the answer I have updated my question, I have a new error which most likely relates to the package I am using for svg.